# How to check if EWS Contact.Birthday property exists

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

Within my C# EWS application, I am pulling a specific contact and grabbing the properties for them.  I am hung up on  contact.birthday.   I'll probably have the same issue with other date time fields so this would assist in killing two or more birds with one stone :P

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.contact.birthday(v=exchg.80)

I know the property isn't set in my test contact, but everytime it goes to retreive these prop's I get the following message  "This property was requested, but it wasn't returned by the server."

I know the value isn't set, so how do i check for null or prop not set or something like that.  I have tried several different methods without any luck.  I am starting to loose my hair over this one.

Any help or suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 9):

You can check for property existence using `TryGetProperty()` like this:

```
DateTime birthday;
contact.TryGetProperty(ContactSchema.Birthday, out birthday);
```